# SQL Server internal memory get full on SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have a SQL Server database hosted in Azure. Recently we have seen the `avg_memory_usage_percent` showing 100 percent. And it remains there. We checked in `sys.dm_db_resource_stats` DMV. Database size is 150+ GB.

We did try to find out which processes running at that time, but seen nothing or few regular queries running from `sp_who3`.

Can you help, how to find out which process or query is consuming more memory and block it at 100%?

Why is SQL Server not releasing memory?

Comment: Have you temp table and table variable by using memory optimization ? or other in memory tables? please more describe about your server config and you features used in database -- like read only snapshot is on or off ... check database property and say what's you see...

Comment: Is this causing an issue for you? SQL Server is a greedy software. It will use all memory available to hold data pages to avoid a physical read. Once SQL Server start it's memory is empty. Once data pages are loaded they remain there until other pages need to bring into memory or memory is needed for other reasons. Read this https://logicalread.com/2014/12/19/sql-server-memory-buffer-pools-pd01/#.XpcLIlxKi90

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Azure SQL? They are two different products (albeit similar)

Comment: We are using Azure SQL SERVER. Database has configuration of P6(1000 DTU).